# CoCreateInstance returns STG_E_FILENOTFOUND (0x80030002)

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, visual-studio-2012, ole

This line of code worked fine before, but now it returns STG_E_FILENOTFOUND (0x80030002).

```
hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_InternetExplorer, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IID_IWebBrowser2, (LPVOID*)&browser);
```

I haven't change any of my codes, I just run it as usual and got this error.
I've also looked for the answer elsewhere but none of them solves this problem.

What possibly causes this? And how to fix it?

Here's the full code, "browser" is IWebBrowser2's variable.

```
HRESULT AUTHORIZATION::Initialize()
{
    if (browser)
        return ERROR_ALREADY_INITIALIZED;
    HRESULT hr = OleInitialize(NULL);
    if (!SUCCEEDED(hr))
        return hr;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_InternetExplorer, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IID_IWebBrowser2, (LPVOID*)&browser);
    if (!SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        OleUninitialize();
        return hr;
    }
    browser->put_RegisterAsBrowser(VARIANT_TRUE);
    browser->put_RegisterAsDropTarget(VARIANT_FALSE);
    browser->put_StatusBar(VARIANT_FALSE);
    browser->put_ToolBar(FALSE);
    browser->put_Resizable(VARIANT_FALSE);
    browser->put_Width(default_dlg_width);
    browser->put_Height(default_dlg_height);
    return hr;
}
```

Comment: Internet Explorer is borken.  Try running it, try re-installing it, etc.

Comment: I've tried re-installed it for 2 times, not working.